# Python prints text in next line

Tags: python

Hi I am reading a text from sample.txt which contains the value 'a'. But when I print it like this-

```
content = open(filepath,'r')
text = content.readlines()
print(text + ',')
```

Expected output - `a,`
Output obtained -

```
a
,
```

Because of this I am facing issue. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because there is `\n` character at the end of the line where `a` is found. Try using this:

```
print(text.strip() + ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

In python3 this is the default print behaviour, to change it use:

```
print(text + ',', end='')
```